# Nifi GetSolr processor not working

Tags: apache, solr, apache-nifi

When run the GetSolr processor using Nifi for the first time it extracts the data from Solr.
But, If I run it for second time it doesn't fetches the data from Solr.
Could anybody please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is meant to do incremental extraction, so after the first time it would be getting only data that is newer than the data previously fetched.

If you right click on the processor and view state, there is an option to clear state which should set it back to the beginning.

If this does not answer your question, please show how you have configured GetSolr and which version of NiFi you are using.

[image]

Comment: I am using Nifi 1.4.0. I didn't see that view state option for my processor. May I know for which version of Nifi this feature is provided.

Comment: See the screenshot I attached, View State is available on all 1.x releases

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan